# How to give an extent when putting a label on the right of an arrow in tikz-cd?

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd, arrowwithtext

I want to put the function names on the outer side of my arrows

and for some it means that I should put them on the right of the arrow:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
 & {A+1} \arrow[dd, dotted, "{[f,g]}"] &  \\
A \arrow[ru, "in_A^{A+1}"] \arrow[rd, "f" right] & & 1 \arrow[lu, "in_1^{A+1}" right] \arrow[ld, "g" ] \\
 & C & \\
\end{tikzcd}
```

resulting in

[image: Coproduct A+1]

But, as you see, `in_1^{A+1}` and `f` is too close to the arrow.

How can I give a distance on the right for the labels?

Comment: Don't use `right`, this sets `anchor=west` which means that the node is put *on* the line with its west anchor. Use `above right` (`anchor=south west`), or even better, use the automatic position provided by TikZ and use [`swap`/`'`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf./tikz/swap): `"in_1^{A+1}"'` or `"in_1^{A+1}" swap`. The same for `"f"'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the labels left or right using the `right=<length>` and `left=<length>` options. To make them still look in the centre of the arrow, you can adjust `pos=...` as needed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 & {A+1} \arrow[dd, dotted, "{[f,g]}"] &  \\
A \arrow[ru, "in_A^{A+1}"] \arrow[rd, "f" left=0.5cm,pos=0.75] & & 1 \arrow[lu, "in_1^{A+1}" right=0.5cm,pos=0.75] \arrow[ld, "g" ] \\
 & C & \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]